# Ensure second script loads only after the first

Tags: javascript, jquery

Jquery is loading after a custom plugin (elevateZoom). Causing the elevateZoom to fail.

Is there a workaround for this?

Please note: Due to policy I can only change the body text.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/default/files/jquery.elevateZoom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#zoom_01").elevateZoom(); 
  }); 
</script>

<p>
  <img id="zoom_01" alt="" data-entity-type="" data-entity-uuid=""
       data-zoom-image="/sites/default/files/2017-06/Ipad-with-loupe.png"
       src="/sites/default/files/2017-06/Ipad-with-loupe-small.png" />
</p>
```

The error message in console is the following:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'
```

Live link - https://www.workbooks.com/test-jquery-zoom

Comment: reverse the order of those scripts tag: `1. jQuery; 2. everything else which depends on jQuery`.

Comment: what's the error output?

Comment: I switched the order and it made no difference?

Answer (score 1):

your website has a Content Security Policy that prevents you loading jQuery from CDN.

The live site you linked has the following signature for `Content-Security-Policy` header:

```
Content-Security-Policy:script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https://www.youtube.com/ https://maps.googleapis.com ; object-src 'self'
```

You either need to add `ajax.googleapis.com` domain to that policy or host jQuery in one of the sites thats already whitelisted.

Comment: I'm more alarmed that someone had the foresight to use a CSP, but the brain-death to include `'unsafe-eval'` and `'unsafe-inline'` in there. They *literally* say "unsafe" and yet...

Answer (score 0):

Give the script tags in this order

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/default/files/jquery.elevateZoom.min.js"></script>
```

This makes the browser to load jquery first and then the plugin next. You can try using requirejs library. It can load the js files asynchronously and has the feature of loading the dependencies first and the plugins next.

Comment: Is someone still using requirejs these days? :D

Comment: I know its a bit old. But it would be easy for beginners.

Comment: I completely and respectfully disagree: async loaders like requirejs are surprisingly difficult for beginners. And for that reason alone I would take that requirejs recommendation with a grain of salt. Besides, ES2015 already standardized modules - why not go that way? There was also a good discussion on the topic in reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/3azxtj/requirejs_vs_browserify_vs_webpack/

Comment: Thanks, I've switched the script tags order (see live page - link above) but it made no difference. If I add another library e.g. Requirejs won't I run into the same problem as Jquery isn't loading first?

Comment: Actually I think I know what the error is, I believe it's Drupal 8's security settings blocking the Jquery CDN.

Comment: Let me see if I can add it.

Comment: Nope Jquery should already be running across the site, so this isn't the issue - back to square 1!

Comment: Can you confirm jQuery is running. I can see jQuery not defined error in the console.